# Unable to capture order of nodes after Drag and Drop in igTree (Infragistics IgniteUI)

Tags: drag-and-drop, infragistics, igtree

- Am not able to capture the updated order of nodes in DragDropTree

  - However Am able to capture the order of nodes when a node is checked or unchecked.Because "nodeCheckStateChanged" event triggered which captures the object as shown in below screenshot. newCheckedNodes has the nodes in updated order[image]
  - Gone through list of events fired when we do drag and drop but none of them capture the order of nodes checked. https://www.igniteui.com/help/api/2018.1/ui.igtree
  - Is there any alternate way by which I can capture the order of checked nodes when I do drag and drop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make use of method as shown below in the nodeDropped event which will have the latest order of the nodes checked.

```
nodeDropped: function (evt, ui) {

                    //This will have the latest order of nodes checked
                    var nodes = treeElement.igTree("checkedNodes");
}
```